# Selecting the hyperlink text from the second td from a table with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I have the following html page...

```
<input type=text id="search">
<table>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td><a href="">Some text...</a></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

This code runs in a PHP loop

And I have the following jquery code already....

```
$("#search").on("keyup", function() {
    var value = $(this).val();

    $("table tr").each(function(index) {
        if (index !== 0) {

            $row = $(this);

            var id = $row.find("td:first").text();

            if (id.indexOf(value) !== 0) {
                $row.hide();
            }
            else {
                $row.show();
            }
        }
    });
});
```

The problem is I need to change the

```
$row.find("td:first").text();
```

to the second td with hyperlink.

I thought it was simple

```
$row.find("td:nth-child(2) a").text();
```

But this doesn't works... Also doesn't works,

```
$row.find("td:eq(2) a:eq(0)").text();
```

I don't know how to select the hyperlink text ( Some text ... ) from the second td...

I need to search through all hyperlinks if a certain text is found....

Comment: SO basically you're building a Search input that will search only for a specific text-value **inside the links hrefs** (and show those rows) right? So only the href attribute value, right? What about the field text? BTW, FYI it's never a good UX and UI to build a Search feature based on something a user **cannot actually see**! Take this for example: `<a href="https://some-website.com?p=123&type=files">Documents</a>` the User-visible text *"Documents"* has nothing to do with what the program would possibly filter as a match if he started typing *`type`* in the search field.

Comment: Ps... if instead you use `$("table tbody tr")` - than you don't need to do `if (index !== 0) {` if all you wanted was to ignore the TH elements in the THEADs TR.

Answer (score 0):

**Filter** your rows by the child elements **attribute** `[href*=""]` containing `*=` a value.
Notice that this is not the best way to build Search functionality, since users most probably  *1:* never search URIs, *2:* they will not understand how is the result related to their search query if the **visible result** has nowhere to be seen the term they searched for**.

But here you go anyways.

PS: the below code will also work if you have **multiple** *HREF* attributed elements in a single row!

```js
const $rows = $("#items").find("tr"); // Collect all TBODY's TR

function searchHref(val) {
  val = val.trim(); // Trim it, you don't want spaces to account
  
  if (!val) return $rows.removeClass("is-hidden"); // Show all if empty search
  
  // Get rows which contain one or more [href] elements
  // containing the search value:
  const $rowsMatch = $rows.filter((i, TR) => $('[href*="'+ val +'"]', TR).length);
  
  // Hide all but the matching ones:
  $rows.not($rowsMatch).addClass('is-hidden');
  
  // Show matching ones:
  $rowsMatch.removeClass('is-hidden');
}

$("#search").on("keyup", function() {
  searchHref(this.value);
});
```

```css
.is-hidden { display: none; }
```

```html
<input type=text id="search" placeholder="Search by URI">
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>id</th>
      <th>desc</th>
      <th>nvm</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="items">
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td><a href="https://www.google.com">Popular search engine</a></td>
      <td>google</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td><a href="https://www.stackoverflow.com">Programming Q&amp;A</a></td>
      <td>stackoverflow</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td><a href="https://area51.stackexchange.com/">Aliens</a></td>
      <td>area51</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
```